# javascript efficient collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, processing

I have a processing game where I am having serious lag problems with collision detection. I am using the most effective code I can think of however after about 9 levels in The game gets unbearably laggy. I would show you the code but site wont handle my less thans.

If you want to check the program out you can find it here:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/tanks-v1245/6637554186715136
under the tankMelee function ~line 160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most games use quadtree structures to manage the colisions, you should [read about it](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/03/21/javascript-quadtree-implementation/).

Anyways, if you are having lag after X levels is possible that you are storing all the objects and checking them out every loop, and not just the object in the current scene or level.

Comment: but this is a real time thing - the enemy has to check for bullets, walls ,and the player, the lag after levels is a "I have to check more things" issue

Comment: Understood, have a peek in the link i provided, theres a demo cheking docens of objects un real time, quadtree is used in real games, give it a try